# Как фильтровать Generic Foreign Key в Django-orm

Tags: python, sql, django, ооп, orm

есть модель

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

class TaggedItem(models.Model):
    tag = models.SlugField()
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.tag
```

Как отфильтровать по аттрибуту связанной модели? Ведь не все связанные модели могут иметь поле 'name'

```
TaggedItem.objects.filter(content_object__name='guido')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем коде не просто связанные модели - они связаны через обобщение (через промежуточную таблицу `ContentType`). Этот вид связей несколько отличается от обычных. На англоязычном so есть наглядный [пример](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28332663/filter-generic-foreign-key) по фильтрации подобной связи.

Вы не можете обратиться к связанной модели напрямую, чтобы сделать фильтр по полю в ней, тк у вас с ней нет прямой связи. И такой код не сработает:
    `TaggedItem.objects.filter(content_object__name='guido')`

Без явного указания связи для вас должно сработать это:

```
mark = ContentModel.objects.get(name='guido')
contentModel = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(ContentModel)
primary_citations = TaggedItem.objects.filter(content_type=contentModel, content_object=mark)
```

(Пожалуй, аргумент content_type можно опустить)

Более удобным способом сделать то, что вы хотите, может быть явное указание обратной связи на полиморфную модель в связанной модели:

```
class ContentModel(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    tags = GenericRelation(TaggedItem, related_query_name='bookmark')

TaggedItem.objects.filter(bookmark__name='guido')
```

Можете так же глянуть пример из документации [enter link description here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#reverse-generic-relations).

И наконец, если вам нужно отфильтровать `TaggedItem` по нескольким связанным объектам, вы можете использовать `object_id__in`:

```
marks = list( ContentModel.objects.filter(name='guido').values_list('id', flat=True))
primary_citations = TaggedItem.objects.filter( object_id__in=marks)
```

Полезные ссылки: [тыц](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37060222/filtering-an-inner-field-within-genericforeignkey)
 и [тыц](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27695611/query-filter-based-on-genericforeignkeys-fields)

Надеюсь, я ответил на ваш вопрос. Вопрос хороший, плюсую